# update Users в профиле

Tags: laravel

есть таблица Users и UsersAttributes у них связь 1к1, как мне сохранить в attributes телефон

роут такой

```
Route::post('/', 'UserController@edit')->name('updateuser');
```

форма такая

```
<form action="{{ route('updateuser') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="grid">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="data-item">
                            <label for="">Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" placeholder="ignatevilya@yandex.ru" name="email" value="{{ $profile->email }}">
                        </div>

                        <div class="data-item">
                            <label for="">Номер телефона:</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="+79343543321" name="phone" value="{{ $profile->attributes->phone }}">
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn-green">Сохранить изменения</button>
                </form>
```

сделал так

```
  $attributes = UsersAttributes::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                                        ->update(['photo' => $request->newphoto]);
```

но ошибка

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: update `users_attributes` set `photo` = /tmp/php0T0xBF, `updated_at` = 2018-09-11 20:52:53 where `user_id` = 22)
```

Comment: решил добавил в модель  public $timestamps = false;

Answer (score 0):

```
$attributes = UsersAttributes::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                                        ->update(['photo' => $request->newphoto]);
```

так писать не так уж хорошо если ты используеш ларавел и relatioships лутше пиши свой код таким оброзом

```
$id=Auth::user()->id;
$attributes= User::find($id)->UsersAttributes->update(['photo' => $request->newphoto]);
```